# Eliminar parte del href - href amigable

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, href

Hola mi duda es que tengo mis href de esta manera
`<a class="nav-link" href="?peticion=que-es">Qué es</a>`
y en mi URL se ve de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que no aparezca el ?peticion=
para que mi URL quede nada mas como /que-es

quiero utilizar el .htaccess para realizar esta accion de que no aparezca

Lo que pasa es que ese ?peticion es mi condicional para el switch
y esto lo hago a traves de un controlador entonces necesito que ?peticion= se quite siempre no solo con ese caso del que-es en especifico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mis href estan de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

tratando de entender tu situacion es que lo que buscas es elimitar el parametro `?peticion` de tu link

Para eso primero tienes que configurar tu `.htaccess` incluyendo el `mod_rewrite`
mas o menos asi

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?petcion=$1 [NC,L]`

y tu switch quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
$peticion = stripslashes($_GET["peticion"]);
if(empty($_GET["peticion"])){
    $peticion = "inicio"
}
switch($peticion){
   //insert procedure
}
```

Espero te sirva de algo, saludos y corrígeme si tengo mal la idea.,